# udev rules not working

Tags: linux, networking, udev

sorry for my English....

I am with Linux Mint

I to try to change my interface name but without result...

The steps which I to does...

First search for my interface name and mac from it,

```
ip a
```

to come, interface name **enp0s3**, mac address **08:00:27:2e:7a:49**.

Seconds set down the interface,

```
sudo ip link set dev enp0s3 down
```

Rename the device name, I'll change to **eth0**.

Call the **70-persistent-net.rules** file,

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

and write,

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:2e:7a:49", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

I call the **interfaces** file,

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and write,

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.178.48
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.178.1
```

Then, the computer new start...

On Terminal write,

```
ip a
```

but have similar interface name, **enp0s3**.

Can Please someone help me with this problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this methods](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182184):

You basically have two options:

1. You disable the assignment of fixed names, so that the unpredictable kernel names are used again. For this, simply mask udev's rule file for the default policy:

`$ ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`

2. You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your own .link files in /etc/systemd/network/, then choose an explicit name or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your interfaces. See systemd.link(5) for more information.

You pass the `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line

I tested systemd.link method. It is works!
[image: systemd.link]

Comment: Very Thanks for your answer!, I do `sudo ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules`, and  new start, but the interface name not change...

Comment: systemd.link method works! See my updated answer.

Comment: I don't if to play one's part, but I to try it on VirtualBox...

Comment: Very Thanks for your patience... I think my problem missing a step.., where should to write `[Match]` and `[link]` ?

Comment: @dsaj34v I am test only this(systemd) method. I am not test udev rule link method. Of course reboot needed for take effect.

Comment: I found the problem!, on my file `sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, I to write `KERNEL=="eth*"`,  when does not it, as here to say https://askubuntu.com/questions/767786/changing-network-interfaces-name-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Now to come to my new interface name!, `eth0`...  I wish your a niceeeeee Day!

Comment: @dsaj34v Nice! :-)